# Troublshooting analog output on OpenSuse Leap 15.1

Tags: opensuse, alsa

I recently upgraded my OpenSuse Leap 15.1. Since the upgrade, my analog output stopped working. When I connect my headphone, there is no sound. I tested my headphone with my phone and it's working fine. What steps can I take to troubleshoot this? I am adding some information about the system below:

Alsa Firmware: alsa-firmware-1.0.29-lp151.3.3.1.noarch

Cards: 1 [HDMI]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
HDA Intel PCH at 0xef128000 irq 129

Asound version: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k4.12.14-lp151.28.79-default

Alsa Information: [here](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=2a7fae318a5d90f5c19a7067326400cd8f275163)

If more information is needed please comment and I will add them.

Comment: check `dmesg` and syslog for anything suspicious.

Comment: Is there anything in particular I am looking for? I do not have much experience with dmesg.

Comment: Hard to say, but if the kernel is aware of an error it will probably report it. You can update your question with dmesg output and mask all sensitive data. Maybe someone will see what's going on there.